# Checkbox Value not populating

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I could not figure out why checkbox is not displaying value . the original code is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@row.Checkbox.Name" value="@row.Checkbox.Text"/>
```

generated HTML Is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkparent" value=" I am the parent or legal guardian of the named child/children in my family membership and I give consent for them to take part in organised paddling activities (Kayak and/or Canoe) and I agree they will abide by the rules and regulations of Totnes Canoe Club at all times."/>
```

I tried to put generated html directly in page but still it does not show value . 
what i see is only the checkbox box.

Comment: You need to create a label or similar element if your wanting to display some text.

Comment: And typically the value of a checkbox is either true or false i.e. is bound to a boolean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `checkbox`'s value cannot be used for showing text. You need to put a `div` or similar next to the checkbox. Like so:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkparent" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;"/>
    <div>
        I am the parent or legal guardian of the named child/children in my family membership and I give consent for them to take part in organised paddling activities (Kayak and/or Canoe) and I agree they will abide by the rules and regulations of Totnes Canoe Club at all times.
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to make this easy for the user, you should attach a click handler to the text (assuming jQuery):

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkparent" name="chkparent" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;"/>
    <div id="chktext" style="cursor:pointer;">
        I am the parent or legal guardian of the named child/children in my family membership and I give consent for them to take part in organised paddling activities (Kayak and/or Canoe) and I agree they will abide by the rules and regulations of Totnes Canoe Club at all times.
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#chktext").on("click", function(){
            if ($("#chkparent").is(":checked")) {
               $("#chkparent").prop("checked", false);
            } else {
               $("#chkparent").prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you use jquery to do this when you can use a `<label>`

Comment: Good point! I am biased, I always create custom checkboxes without the input element.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off creating a strongly typed view model with a bool property for this and decorating it with a display name.

The display name can then be used to render a label for as follows:

***View Model***

```
public class AViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Selection 1")]
    public bool MySelection { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MySelection)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MySelection)
```

[**Working example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhRS4j)

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the `row.Checkbox` value in your controller before returning the View, to check whether the checkbox should or should not be checked.

Then, assign that information to a ViewBag variable:

```
ViewBag.checked = "checked";
```

And in your View:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@row.Checkbox.Name" @ViewBag.checked/>
```

This will produce an HTML of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@row.Checkbox.Name" checked/>
```

if the checkbox should be checked and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@row.Checkbox.Name"/>
```

for an unchecked checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Without modifing your current model, code should look like this:

```
<label for="@row.Checkbox.Name">@row.Checkbox.Text @Html.CheckBox(row.Checkbox.Name, false)</label>
```